# Replacement of sprocket

Tags: cassette

When should the front sprocket and back cassette be replaced.I have a 2014 Trek 520 Touring bike with 6500 miles and am planning a cross country touring trip in August.

Comment: They should be replaced when they are worn out.  Every serious cyclist should have a chain wear gauge.  Your better bike shops have a wear gauge for sprockets, but a common test for the front is to see how far you can pull a relatively new chain off the sprocket.  Generally chains are good for 2000-3000 miles, rear clusters about twice that, and front rings every 2-3 rear clusters.  But a worn chain causes sprockets to wear much faster.

Comment: That assumes a clean drivetrain -- grit can chew through those things much quicker.

Comment: And most manufacturers say 900 - 1000 miles, for best performance.

Comment: There are a number of similar questions with answers already written.  Did you search the site before asking a new question? http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-to-tell-when-to-replace-cassette/9128#9128

Comment: @zenbike -- 900-1000 miles for a cassette???  Maybe if you only ride on a sandy beach.

Comment: Actually, that's the recommendation for the chain, as you know. We've had this discussion many times. Your words: "Generally chains are good for 2000-3000 miles".